# Ubuntu Not Starting Second RAID Array

Tags: raid, mdadm, ubuntu-18.04, raid0

Before I start let me say that I am by no means an expert with this stuff, if you see something that you would have done differently let me know.

Ok, so I have a Ubuntu 18.04 server with a boot drive and 4 8T drives. My plan was to make 2 RAID 0 arrays, that would sync with rsync every night. I don't want to accidentally delete something forever so I decided to do the rsync route. I made my first array a couple of days ago, tested it, rebooted the server to make sure the settings stayed and then copied almost 3T of data to it.

I then went to make the second array, and that went great. However, whenever I reboot I have to rebuild the array by typing `sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md1 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sde`. Once I do that it mounts just like normal, but that deletes all the data on it. I tried `sudo mdadm -A /dev/md1` and `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan`, neither one will bring the array up or say anything for that matter. mdstat also doesn't say that I have a drive /dev/md1

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid0] [linear] [multipath] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid0 sdb[0] sdd[1]
      15627788288 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

unused devices: <none>
```

Here is my mdadm.conf and fstab just in case

mdadm.conf

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=server-1:0 UUID=bc5145a0:d633e28a:940ddf09:7cfc2477
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=1.2 name=server-1:1 UUID=8a575273:38284856:a0a90411:41ef2a24
```

Fstab

```
/dev/md0 /mnt/Media ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0
/dev/md1 /mnt/Backup ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a second account you used to edit your original post?  If so, you should merge accounts

Answer (score 1):

You created the second RAID 0 using your boot drive (`/dev/sda`) after you installed the system on it.  It's amazing it still booted!

You have to create the array during the OS installation process.  It might be easier to use LVM to combine two drives for the boot/root volume, rather than deal with RAID 0 for that.